# Can I store the same option value for more than one toggle button in a control box?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a list of questions each with 4 possible answers that are displayed as toggle buttons on my form. What I want to do is if the user chooses either of the first two buttons, the Option Value stored is "1", if they choose either of the last two buttons, the Option Value stored should be "0". The option values must be different for each toggle button in a control group. Is there a way to recode the toggle buttons to store the desired response? (I work in psychology, thus the bait and switch of offering 4 choices to the user when really only two responses are recorded).

Here is what I have tried:

I tried thinking about a recode as jcarroll suggested, but this is a circular reference:

```
Private Sub Q1_Click()
If Me.Q1 = 1 Or 2 Then
Me.Q1 = 1
Else:
Me.Q1 = 0
End If
End Sub
```

I could recode into another variable but that is just as clunky as using a SQL statement on the data post-hoc, for instance:

NewVariable=Iif([Q1]=1,1,iif([Q1]=2,1,0)

Finally, I tried to code have both toggle buttons have the same Option Value (which causes both to look pressed if either is pressed) and recode the unpressed toggle button's back color. But while my code looks correct to me, this did not change the pressed color of the toggle button (which I think has to do with over riding toggle button design settings):

```
Private Sub Frame5_Click()
If Toggle8.Value = True Then
Toggle9.BackColor = &HFF00&
Else
Toggle9.BackColor = &H8000000F
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you just add something to the code which says if 1 or 2 then 1 else 0?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "gimme teh codez" / "write the whole thing for me"

Comment: Why not store the actual response (1-4) - then you can maybe get some interesting info out of whether a particular one of the "duplicate" responses was more-often selected.

Comment: This is the best bet right now. Store the actual response and then recode with a SQL query later, but was trying to think about how to do it on the form.

Comment: @TSS could you post the answer in an answer now? The post has been reopened.

Answer (score 0):

I could not come up with any programming solutions on the form itself to solve this. The alternative is that I wrote a procedure to apply to the data after it is collected which will be stored as 1,2,3,4 to convert it to 0 or 1. This procedure also sums up the 1's. I have 50 variables/questions that will be passed through this procedure (as well as another like it that converts 3&4 to 1).

```
Public Function Recode1(ParamArray arg()) As Variant
Dim Size As Integer, skips As Integer, i As Integer, result As Variant
'Recodes first two toggle buttons as "1" for AQ assessment

Size = UBound(arg) + 1

For i = 0 To Size - 1

If IsNull(arg(i)) Or Not (IsNumeric(arg(i))) Or arg(i) = -99 Then
skips = skips + 1
Else
If arg(i) = 1 Or arg(i) = 2 Then
result = result + 1
Else:
result = result + 0
End If
End If
End sub
```